# Arduino function not executing

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

I have the following function implemented in an Arduino sketch.  The problem is that when the function is called within the loop function, it does not execute, and the program halts.  Oddly enough, even the function call on the previous line ceases to execute if this function is called.  If the function call is commented out, the program seems to execute without it, just not completing the required task.  Any help on this peculiar issue is appreciated.

Notes:

The sketch executes fine, up until the function call.

The sketch compiles without error

```
movingAverageNode movingAverage::refresh(float r, float p, float h) {

  //create pointers and new node
  movingAverageNode* newNode = new movingAverageNode;
  newNode->roll = r;
  newNode->pitch = p;
  newNode->heading = h;
  movingAverageNode* nodePtr;

  //append last node
  if(!head){
    head = newNode;
    numNodes++;
  }else{
    while(nodePtr->next){
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
    nodePtr->next = newNode;
    numNodes++;
  }

  //remove first node if nessecary
  if (numNodes > NUM_NODES){
    nodePtr = head;
    head = nodePtr->next;
    delete[] nodePtr;
    numNodes--;
  }

  //average all values in list
  float avgRoll;
  float avgPitch;
  float avgHeading;
  nodePtr = head;
  while (nodePtr != NULL){
    avgRoll += nodePtr->roll;
    avgPitch += nodePtr->pitch;
    avgHeading += nodePtr->heading;
    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
  }
  avgRoll /= numNodes;
  avgPitch /= numNodes;
  avgHeading /= numNodes;

  //create new node and return it
  movingAverageNode result;
  result.roll = avgRoll;
  result.pitch = avgPitch;
  result.heading = avgHeading;
  return result;
}
```

If it is helpful, here is the loop:

```
void loop(void) {
  Serial.print(F("i"));
  sensors_vec_t orientation;
  movingAverage data;
  movingAverageNode averaged;

  if (ahrs.getOrientation(&orientation)) {
    Serial.print(F("j"));
    data.refreshB();
    averaged = data.refresh(orientation.roll,orientation.pitch,orientation.heading);
    Serial.print(F("k"));
    Serial.println(String(averaged.roll) + "\t" + String(averaged.pitch) + "\t" + String(averaged.heading));
  }

  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really an expert for arduino development, but I'd suspect you have a debugger available to step through your code, and inspect current variable values?

Comment: your probably getting stuck in a the while loop (while (nodePtr != NULL){ or while(nodePtr->next){) does "next" default to null when you create a new object?

Comment: Using a circular buffer would be simpler than a linked list.

Comment: You don't assign the pointer `nodePtr` so here your loop id one on a garbage value  `while(nodePtr->next)` looks like you segfault here

Comment: Is `data` correctly initialized ? Where do you declare `head` ?

Comment: Turns out it was a very stupid mistake on my part.  data was not being correctly initialized.  It was declared in the loop.  If you would like to post this as a formal answer, I would love to accept it so you would get credit for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodePtr` is not set

Try this:

```
movingAverageNode movingAverage::refresh(float r, float p, float h) {

  //create pointers and new node
  movingAverageNode* newNode = new movingAverageNode;
  newNode->roll = r;
  newNode->pitch = p;
  newNode->heading = h;
  movingAverageNode* nodePtr;

  //append last node
  if(!head){
    head = newNode;
    numNodes++;
  }else{
    nodePtr = head;
    while(nodePtr->next){
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
    nodePtr->next = newNode;
    numNodes++;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your change did not fix my issue, but I thank you for your attempt and I will keep the change.

Comment: Check the value of  `numNodes` if it is `0` you have a segfault too

Comment: numNodes defaults to 0, and then increments from there.  So I assume this is causing the error? Any suggestions on how I might go about fixing it?